# auto-populating a web form from excel with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, timer

I am trying to fix an excel macro to auto populate a web form. security settings don't allow the form to be manipulated faster then a person can type in the information. I would like to include a timer to slow the process down to a second per entry but am unsure how to do this. below is the VBA:

```
Sub Load()
On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSHTML.TLB"
    ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\WINDOWS\system32\ieframe.dll"

Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim sURL As String
Dim WPid As String
Dim WPpercent As Double
Dim Total As Double
Dim WPname As String
Dim dblClock As Double
Dim Percent As Double
On Error GoTo Err_Clear

WPid = Range("A2")
sURL = ****
'Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
'oBrowser.Silent = True
'oBrowser.timeout = 60
'oBrowser.navigate sURL
'oBrowser.Visible = True


'Do
  'Wait till the Browser is loaded
'Loop Until oBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE


  'Reads out the object on the website
  'For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
  'Debug.Print oHTML_Element.Name
  'Debug.Print oHTML_Element.Value
  'Next


    Range("B2").Select

    Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
    'oBrowser.Silent = True
    'oBrowser.timeout = 60
    oBrowser.navigate sURL
    oBrowser.Visible = True

    Do
        'Wait till the Browser is loaded
    Loop Until oBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.document

    Do While ActiveCell <> Empty And HTMLDoc.all.PrctRem.Value <> 0
        WPpercent = Round(ActiveCell * 100, 2)
        Percent = HTMLDoc.all.PrctRem.Value
    If Percent = 0 Then Exit Do

        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        WPname = ActiveCell

    If WPpercent > Percent Then
        HTMLDoc.all.QBDPerct.Value = Percent
    Else
        HTMLDoc.all.QBDPerct.Value = WPpercent
    End If
        HTMLDoc.all.QBDLn.Value = WPname


    'Do
    'Loop Until HTMLDoc.all.QBDTot.Value = 100 - Percent And HTMLDoc.all.QBDPerct.Value = 0

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Select

    'Windows("QBD Load Tool").Visible = True
    'MsgBox "Load next Event?"
    'oBrowser.Quit

    'oBrowser.Refresh
    HTMLDoc.all.Insert.Click
    Do While oBrowser.Busy
    Loop

    'Do
        'Wait till the Browser is loaded
    'Loop Until oBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    'Set oBrowser = Nothing


        'dblClock = Timer
        'While Timer < dblClock + 1.3
        'DoEvents
        'Wend

    Loop


oBrowser.Quit
Set oBrowser = Empty
Windows("QBD Load Tool").Activate
MsgBox ("Load Complete. Check QBD and Save")
    Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
    oBrowser.Silent = True
    oBrowser.timeout = 60
    oBrowser.navigate sURL
    oBrowser.Visible = True
Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
Err.Clear
Resume Next

End If


End Sub
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Wait 1 Second:

```
Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this towards the top of your script...it forces the page to fully load before you start to grab data from it.

```
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
```

If the page has not loaded, you can't get the data from it.